# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Window

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know that is their is possibility to hide the check box inside DataGridCheckBoxColumn  for a  particular row ,if yes then how?

I am working in Desktop Application with c#.

Comment: What kind of desktop application? Windows Forms? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Cellformatting event maybe .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx